# String placeholder всегда возвращает запятую вместо точки

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources, decimal

Есть вот такая строка:

```xml
<string name="measure">%1$.1f</string>
```

Пытаюсь получить значение формата `1.11` из Float у которого может быть более чем 2 знака после запятой.

Получаю строку вот так:

```kotlin
val likesCount = (likeCount.toFloat() / ViewConst.HUNDRED_LIKES)
resources.getString(R.string.measure, likesCount)
```

На выходе всегда `1,11`. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

### Способ 1

Формат дробных чисел зависит от выставленной локали, установите дефолтную локаль в onCreate в вашей активити:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    resources.configuration.setLocales(LocaleList(Locale.US))
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    resources.configuration.locale = Locale.US
}
```

### Способ 2

Если не нужно применять локаль глобально, то отформатируйте число с помощью `String.format()`, передав первым аргументом локаль:

```kotlin
val measure = String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", 1.11)
resources.getString(R.string.measure, measure)
```

В xml при этом должно быть `%s` вместо `%f`:

```xml
<string name="measure">%s</string>
```

### Способ 3

Можно явно указать, какой символ вы хотите использовать в качестве разделителя (decimalSeparator), если воспользоваться классом `DecimalFormat`:

```kotlin
val symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols().apply { decimalSeparator = '.' }
val measure = DecimalFormat("#.0", symbols).format(1.11)
resources.getString(R.string.measure, measure)
```

В xml указываем `%s`:

```xml
<string name="measure">%s</string>
```